# Longest Path in Boost Graph

Tags: boost, graph

Sorry if this is a very basic questions for some of you but I'm new to C++ (let alone Boost Graph Library) and couldn't figure out this problem. So far I've been able to formulate/gather code to create a graph using the code below.

Now I'm trying to figure out the code to find the longest path in this graph.

Can someone please help with what would the code be? I was having trouble trying to figure out if/how to traverse through each node and/or edge when trying to find the path?

I have to try to return all the nodes and edges in the longest path.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S. does anyone know if C++ has organized documentation like Javadoc??

```
    #include <boost/graph/dag_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>



int main()
{
  using namespace boost;
  typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, property<vertex_distance_t, double>, property<edge_weight_t, double> > graph_t;
  graph_t g(6);
  enum verts { stationA, stationB, stationC, stationD, stationE, stationF };
  char name[] = "rstuvx";


  add_edge(stationA, stationB, 5000.23, g);
  add_edge(stationA, stationC, 3001, g);
  add_edge(stationA, stationD, 2098.67, g);
  add_edge(stationA, stationE, 3298.84, g);
  add_edge(stationB, stationF, 2145, g);
  add_edge(stationC, stationF, 4290, g);
  add_edge(stationD, stationF, 2672.78, g);
  add_edge(stationE, stationF, 11143.876, g);
  add_edge(stationA, stationF, 1, g);




//Display all the vertices
  typedef property_map<graph_t, vertex_index_t>::type IndexMap;
  IndexMap index = get(vertex_index, g);
  std::cout << "vertices(g) = ";

  typedef graph_traits<graph_t>::vertex_iterator vertex_iter;
  std::pair<vertex_iter, vertex_iter> vp;
  for (vp = vertices(g); vp.first != vp.second; ++vp.first)
      std::cout << index[*vp.first] <<  " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  // ...

   // Display all the edges
    // ...
  std::cout << "edges(g) = " << std::endl;
    graph_traits<graph_t>::edge_iterator ei, ei_end;
    for (tie(ei, ei_end) = edges(g); ei != ei_end; ++ei)
  std::cout << "(" << index[source(*ei, g)] << "," << index[target(*ei, g)] << ") \n";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the example in your boost distribution.
Online : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example.cpp

To make it find the longest path you need to simply inverse the weight (W), either use a Constant - W, or 1/W. If the constant is 0, then it means it's a negation (-W).

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. 

I looked at this example. As I said I'm new to C++ I was hoping to see the code of how I can traverse through the entire graph?

Also, Dijkstra might work on this simple basic graph. But in general for longer/bigger graphs, negating the weights might not be the solution, especially if its not acyclic.

Comment: Check this for graph traversal:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_search.html

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/graph/example/dfs-example.cpp

I think Dijkstra's would also works on bigger graphs (could you specify the reason?). And if the graphs is cyclic, of course the longest path would be infinity.

Comment: Well, from what I know is that we can't use the negative weights with Dijkstra.

However, come to think of it, 1/|W| might work (considering all the edge weights we have are positive anyways).

Thanks a lot. for your feedback.

Comment: That's why I wrote it's Constant - W. When Constant is bigger that max W, we will end up with all positive weights.

Comment: false: take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem The longest path problem is NP-hard. That means simply reversing the graph weights will not work. It will not yield correct results. As a quick-and-dirty approximation to the longest path, simply take the longest road possible from every vertex, starting at an arbitrary point.

Comment: yes answer above is not correct. I'm waiting for correct answer too.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that one has to be careful about sign reversal. Firstly, most shortest path algorithms are only for positive edge graphs. You do have some options (e.g Bellman-Ford algorithm) that generalize to graphs with negative weight, they are not guaranteed to return the optimal answer if there are negative cycles in the graph.